# How to split classes in few-shot classification using CIFAR-10?

Tags: pytorch, artificial-intelligence, meta-learning, few-shot-learning

I want to train a model that perform a few-shot image classification using CIFAR-10. So I have to train the model with a small amount of classes and use the rest of the classes for the testing. I'm wondering if I have only 10 classes, how can i do the split? (For example 6 classes for training and 4 for testing, is it ok?)

Answer (score 0):

I have not completely understand your question. We have three options to say it crudely:

1. Training a model from scratch
2. Fine-tuning a model
3. Use a pre-trained model and use it for few-shot learning

If it is the number 3 is what you are looking for, I would recommend that you look into models like CLIP and see whether they work out for your use case.